# Sorting an array of time-specific tasks of varying importance

Tags: sorting, objective-c, ios

**RULES:**

- Strict tasks must occur at the time the user selected no matter what.
- Flex tasks are in a priority order. Even if there is a gap big enough to fit several flex tasks with lower priority, no flex task can be scheduled until all the tasks with a higher priority are scheduled.
- Flex tasks will continue to be rescheduled accordingly on refresh until a user completes the task.
- Flex tasks can **only** be scheduled in gaps where the gap between strict tasks is bigger than the flex tasks duration.

I'm sharing this logic because I want to improve my coding style and approach. I'm aware there is probably lots of room for improvement.

**Code:**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAndSortAllTasks{


    _strictTasksArray=[self getTasksInTimestampOrder];
    _finalSortedArray=[_strictTasksArray mutableCopy];
    _randomTasksArray=[self getRandomTasks];

    NSLog(@"STRICT:%@",_strictTasksArray);
    NSLog(@"RANDOM:%@",_randomTasksArray);




    if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray.count>0){

        int strict_index=0;
        int insert_index=0;
        int flex_index=0;
        int CurrentTStamp=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

        int UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,TIME_GAP;



        /////////DEAL WITH GAP BETWEEN 'THE NOW' AND FIRST TASK.//////////

        UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP=CurrentTStamp;
        NSMutableDictionary *firstTask=[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"FIRST_TASK:%@",firstTask);
        LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP= [[firstTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP:%d",LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP);

        if(_randomTasksArray.count>0){
            for(flex_index=_randomTasksArray.count-1; flex_index >=0; flex_index--){

                NSMutableDictionary *flexTask=[_randomTasksArray objectAtIndex:flex_index];
                int FLEX_DURATION=[[flexTask objectForKey:@"TASK_DURRATION"] intValue];
                int FLEX_START_TIME=[[flexTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];

                TIME_GAP=LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP-UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP;
                NSLog(@"LOWER_LIMIT:%d | UPPER_LIMIT:%d | GAP:%d",LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,TIME_GAP);
                if(TIME_GAP>FLEX_DURATION){
                    if(FLEX_START_TIME==0){
                        [flexTask setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
                        [_randomTasksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:flex_index withObject:flexTask];
                        UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP=UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+FLEX_DURATION+1;

                    }

                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    NSLog(@"COMPLETED_TOP_LOOP:%@",_randomTasksArray);

        flex_index=0;
        strict_index=0;



        ///if there is not 2 or more tasks no gaps can be created//////
        if(_strictTasksArray.count>1){
            ///START LOOPING FOR STRICT TASK GAPS //////
            int strict_index;
            for(strict_index = 0;strict_index<=_strictTasksArray.count-1;strict_index = strict_index + 1){


                NSMutableDictionary *upperTask=[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:strict_index];
                NSLog(@"UPPER_TASK_MID:%@",upperTask);
                int UPPER_TASK_START_TSTAMP=[[upperTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
                int UPPER_DURATION=[[upperTask objectForKey:@"TASK_DURRATION"] intValue];
                UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP=UPPER_TASK_START_TSTAMP+UPPER_DURATION;

                //If a time gap cannot be created due to there not being another strict task under the current objectAtIndex:strict_index then break the loop.
                if(strict_index+1>_strictTasksArray.count-1){
                    break;
                }


                NSMutableDictionary *lowerTask=[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:strict_index+1];
                LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP= [[lowerTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];

                NSLog(@"UPPER_LIMIT_TOP_LOOP:%d | LOWER_LIMIT__TOP_LOOP:%d",UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP);


               // NSLog(@"FLEX_LOOP:%@",_randomTasksArray);

                    for(flex_index=_randomTasksArray.count-1; flex_index >=0; flex_index--){

                        NSMutableDictionary *flexTask=[_randomTasksArray objectAtIndex:flex_index];
                        NSLog(@"FLEX_TASK_MID_LOOP:%@",flexTask);

                        int FLEX_DURATION=[[flexTask objectForKey:@"TASK_DURRATION"] intValue];
                        int FLEX_START_TIME=[[flexTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
                        if(FLEX_START_TIME==0){
                            int TIME_GAP=LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP-UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP;
                            NSLog(@"TIME_GAP:%d | NEW_UPPER_LIMIT:%d",TIME_GAP,UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP);


                            if(TIME_GAP>FLEX_DURATION){
                                [flexTask setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
                                [_randomTasksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:flex_index withObject:flexTask];
                                UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP=UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1+FLEX_DURATION;

                            }else{
                                //Stop looping random tasks, nothing comes before the next task in line.
                                break;
                            }

                        }


                    }

            }


        }

    NSLog(@"COMPLETED_MIDDLE_LOOP:%@",_randomTasksArray);










    }


    //LOOP THROUGH REMAINING FLEX TASKS AND ADD TO END OF ARRAY////
    //LOOP THROUGH REMAINING FLEX TASKS AND ADD TO END OF ARRAY////
    //LOOP THROUGH REMAINING FLEX TASKS AND ADD TO END OF ARRAY////

    int NEXT_TASK_START_TIME;
    if(_strictTasksArray.count>0){
        NSMutableDictionary *last_task=[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:_strictTasksArray.count-1];
        NSLog(@"LAST_TASK:%@",last_task);
        int LAST_TASK_START_TIME=[[last_task objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];
        int LAST_TASK_DURATION=[[last_task objectForKey:@"TASK_DURRATION"] intValue];
        int LAST_TASK_END_TIME=LAST_TASK_START_TIME+LAST_TASK_DURATION;
        NEXT_TASK_START_TIME=LAST_TASK_END_TIME;

    }else{

        int CurrentTStamp=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NEXT_TASK_START_TIME=CurrentTStamp;
    }

    for(int flex_index=_randomTasksArray.count-1; flex_index >=0; flex_index--){
        NSMutableDictionary *flex_task=[_randomTasksArray objectAtIndex:flex_index];
        NSLog(@"END_FLEX_LOOP:%@",flex_task);
        int FLEX_START_TIME=[[flex_task objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];

        if(FLEX_START_TIME==0){
            int FLEX_DURATION=[[flex_task objectForKey:@"TASK_DURRATION"] intValue];


            [flex_task setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NEXT_TASK_START_TIME]  forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
            [_randomTasksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:flex_index withObject:flex_task];
            NEXT_TASK_START_TIME=NEXT_TASK_START_TIME+1+FLEX_DURATION;

        }


    }





    //////////////////COMBINE AND SORT STRICT + FLEX TASKS///////////////
    //////////////////COMBINE AND SORT STRICT + FLEX TASKS///////////////
    //////////////////COMBINE AND SORT STRICT + FLEX TASKS///////////////
    //////////////////COMBINE AND SORT STRICT + FLEX TASKS///////////////





    NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"COUNT_STRICT:%lu | COUNT_RANDOM:%lu",(unsigned long)_strictTasksArray.count,(unsigned long)_randomTasksArray.count);
    if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count>0){
        newArray=[_strictTasksArray  arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_randomTasksArray];
        NSLog(@"strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count>0)");
    }else if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count==0){
        newArray=_strictTasksArray;
        NSLog(@"else if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count==0");
    }else if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray.count==0){
        NSLog(@"else if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray==0");
        newArray=_randomTasksArray;


    }

    NSLog(@"NEW_ARRAY:%@",newArray);
    NSLog(@"FLEX_ARRAY:%@",_randomTasksArray);

    NSSortDescriptor * brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"TASK_START_TIME" ascending:YES];
    NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
    NSMutableArray * sortedArray = [newArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    _finalSortedArray=sortedArray;
    NSLog(@"FINAL_SORTED_ARRAY:%@",_finalSortedArray);



    return _finalSortedArray;




}
```

**Deeper explanation(cont. reading only if needed)**

This is for a app that aims to combine your todo list and your calendar in a automated way. When a user creates a task they can choose to either include a strict time (strict task) or not (flexible task).

Flexible tasks have a priority to them but don't effect strict tasks so if you have Flex A, B and C, the idea is that you have your strict tasks array and you can loop through the time gaps (current timestamp to start of strict task 1, strict task 1 to strict task 2 etc)

The idea is we figure out how big each of these gaps are, see if the flex task with the highest priority fits in that gap, if it does fit then schedule that flex task, reduce the gap accordingly and continue the loop to see if the next highest priority flex task will fit in the remaining gap.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. You have certainly come to the right place, and with the right spirit, if you are looking for constructive criticism. I hope you get some great reviews!

Comment: Don't worry, you get the carrot now, you'll get the stick once you get some answers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I see many things that can be cleaned up here just to make the code clear and readable; I'm not sure I can be comprehensive with those, and because of that I'm going to mostly ignore the logic. I've tried to break the points down roughly by type-of-thing, and to go from easy-to-fix to more involved, although some items may straddle categories.

### Consistency:

Sometimes operators (`=`, `>=`, `+`) in this code have spaces around them, sometimes not. Spaces are preferred style these days, but doing one or the other all the time in your code is the more important thing.

The asterisks in object variable declarations usually abut the variable name -- `NSMutableDictionary *firstTask` -- but in one place they're stood off with a space -- `NSSortDescriptor * brandDescriptor`. Here again, which style you use doesn't matter one iota (I personally like the latter, but most people seem to prefer the former) as long as it's the same throughout.

Likewise, a line with multiple declarations `int UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP,TIME_GAP;` is preceded by individual initializations like `int flex_index=0;`. Pick one style and be consistent.

Inter-line whitespace is haphazard: some blocks have an empty line at the top, some have none, at least one has two. Closing braces are not always lined up with their headers, and in one place have blank lines between them, in another not. It looks like you're trying to use whitespace inside blocks in a good way, to make groups out of statements that logically act together, but this could be more carefully considered in nearly every case.

### Naming:

Don't name your methods `get...` anything. That has a special meaning in Cocoa; the method is expected to take a buffer of some kind to fill, and return information indirectly. None of the methods you've shown here fit the bill.

You say "Flex tasks are in a priority order". Why then is the variable holding them called "random"? That strongly implies that there's no order to the list. Call this simply `flexTasks`, or `prioritizedFlexTasks` if this is a sorted version of another collection.

Don't give variables capitalized names. In Objective-C, all-caps names are generally reserved for preprocessor definitions, things that never change. `UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP`, `LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP`, and `TIME_GAP` are all variables whose values change repeatedly. They should be called `upper_limit_tstamp`, `lower_limit_tstamp`, and `time_gap`.

The underscore in `_strictTasksArray` and the others implies that they are ivars. If that's so, consider whether it's necessary to set these ivars every time this method is called, or if they should already be set, and just accessed here. Also, if they're not being used elsewhere in the class, they should be locals, not ivars. Finally, if `_finalSortedArray` *is* an ivar, you most likely shouldn't be returning it from this method. Let access to it go through its getter method.

(Try not to name things `...Array`. The arrays in this method would be fine named `strictTasks`, `randomTasks`, `finalTasks`, and `sortedTasks`. The plural clearly indicates that we've got a list.)

### Types and framework methods:

`timeIntervalSince1970` returns `NSTimeInterval`, not `int`. If you want to truncate (it's a `double` under the hood), use an explicit conversion.

All of the data access takes the form `[[firstTask objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue]`. At first I thought you [were storing quantities in strings](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped); I later see that the dictionary values are `NSNumber`s, but still, consider replacing the dicts with a data class which holds the information you need, explicitly in the datatype you'll be using:

```
@interface CKLTask : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic) int startTime; 
@property (nonatomic) int duration; 
// etc. 
@end.
```

This makes your code more readable and lets your tools help you, by turning mistakes into compiler errors.

Alternatively, at least make [named constants for your string keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538996/constants-in-objective-c). Notice that you've misspelled "duration" in `@"TASK_DURRATION"`. If you were to spell it correctly elsewhere, or misspell this key in a different way, your access would fail (see the caution at the end for one possible consequence).

This loop:

```
for(flex_index=_randomTasksArray.count-1; flex_index >=0; flex_index--){

    NSMutableDictionary *flexTask=[_randomTasksArray objectAtIndex:flex_index];
```

might be better written with fast enumeration:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *flexTask in [_randomTasksArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
```

(I know you're using that index inside the loop; see below about that.)

`NSArray` has a handy `lastObject` method that you can use instead of subtracting one from the count manually:

```
NSMutableDictionary *last_task=[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:_strictTasksArray.count-1];
```

Use [`NSArray` literals and subscripting](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/). `[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:0];` is `_strictTasksArray[0]`.

Here:

```
NSSortDescriptor * brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"TASK_START_TIME" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
```

You could more easily write:

```
NSArray * sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"TASK_START_TIME" ascending:YES]];
```

### Variable scope and declarations:

The variable `flex_index` is declared at the top of a block, and repeatedly used to control separate iterations. Unless you need to reuse the last index *value* from one iteration to the next -- say you were searching for something -- don't reuse the variable like this. Declare it as close as possible to the place it's going to be used. In this case, that's in each `for`'s initializer. The `UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP`, `LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP`, and `TIME_GAP` variables would also benefit from being redeclared inside of each block where they are necessary. Leveraging variable scope helps you keep track of values and flow; it makes it easier to see what's going on both while reading the code and at runtime when you need to debug.

This is doubly true of `strict_index`. It is initialized at the top `int strict_index=0;`, not touched during the loop, set to 0 again, and then *redeclared* in an inner scope, at which point that *new variable* is also initialized to 0. It doesn't appear to be needed *at all* until the later point.

A similar problem with `_finalSortedArray`: it is initialized with an empty mutable array at the top, then not used until the end. There, the value is unconditionally discarded and replaced. Don't waste the allocation, and if the variable isn't needed until the end, don't even declare it until then.

There's no reason to declare `CurrentTStamp` in the two places that you do so, because you immediately assign it to `UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP` and don't use it for anything else. Just assign the value you want directly to `UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP`.

### Conditionals and assignments:

There is a test for `if(_randomTasksArray.count>0){` inside the block wrapped by `if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray.count>0){`. We already know that the former is true inside the latter. It doesn't need to be tested again; just perform the actions.

The majority of this method is taken up by a huge conditional block of the form `if( condition ){ // Do 100 lines of stuff } // Do nothing`. The size of the block indicates that the method's purpose is strongly tied to whatever's happening inside the block. Therefore, it should be the expected path, not the conditional path. Converting this to `if( !condition ){ // Do nothing } // Do 100 lines of stuff` would be beneficial to clarity.

This is easy here: this method **has nothing to do** if there's nothing in either array; just **return an empty array immediately**.

In other cases, if you can't reverse the condition<sup>*</sup>, you should strongly consider breaking the computation up into small, nameable parts, [putting those parts into methods or functions](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/), and using these wrappers to boost the clarity of the code.

There is also a similar conditional later: `if( condition ){ // Do a bunch of stuff } else { // Just bail out }`:

```
if(FLEX_START_TIME==0){
    int TIME_GAP=LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP-UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP;
    NSLog(@"TIME_GAP:%d | NEW_UPPER_LIMIT:%d",TIME_GAP,UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP);


    if(TIME_GAP>FLEX_DURATION){
        [flexTask setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
        [_randomTasksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:flex_index withObject:flexTask];
        UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP=UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1+FLEX_DURATION;

    }else{
        //Stop looping random tasks, nothing comes before the next task in line.
        break;
    }

}
```

Reading this is sort of like reading a joke with a bad punchline. Again, reverse the branching:

```
if( !condition ){ 
    // Bail out
} 
// No else 
// Do stuff
```

That way, you don't need the `else` clause at all; much clearer flow, less surprising, and more readable with less indentation.

After completing your initial large `if` block that tests whether both the arrays are empty, you have this: `if(_strictTasksArray.count>0){`. Here again, you already tested this. If there's no way to combine the actions, and cover this on the same branch, you can at least save the result first `BOOL strictTasksEmpty = ([_strictTasksArray count] == 0);` Naming the condition is also a big boost for readability.

This is where `flex_index` is being used, but isn't actually needed:

```
[flexTask setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UPPER_LIMIT_TSTAMP+1] forKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"];
[_randomTasksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:flex_index withObject:flexTask];
```

`flexTask` is a pointer to a mutable dictionary in an array. When the dictionary is mutated via that pointer, it hasn't left the array. The values are updated in the dictionary, and you see them whether you access it via the pointer or the array. This replacement operation is unnecessary; the dictionary is *already where you're trying to put it*, so just perform the mutation and be done.

This whole block requires reworking:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count>0){
    newArray=[_strictTasksArray  arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_randomTasksArray];
    NSLog(@"strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count>0)");
}else if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count==0){
    newArray=_strictTasksArray;
    NSLog(@"else if(_strictTasksArray.count>0 && _randomTasksArray.count==0");
}else if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray.count==0){
    NSLog(@"else if(_randomTasksArray.count>0 && _strictTasksArray==0");
    newArray=_randomTasksArray;
}
```

First, the name `newArray` is descriptive of nothing; it should probably be `combinedTasks`, or just used as the `finalTasks` array. Next, it's declared as a mutable array, but the assigned value is an *immutable* array in two out of three cases. Finally, as with `_finalSortedArray` at the top, this creates an object and immediately discards it (unless both of the other arrays are empty, but if that were true you should have aborted the method a long time ago because there's no work to do, and also...)

The conditionals here are needless: if either of the arrays being combined are empty, they will simply not contribute any objects to the result of `arrayByAdding...`. These eleven lines can be condensed to one:

```
NSArray * combinedTasks = [_strictTasksArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_randomTasksArray];
```

(If the arrays are both empty, this results in an empty array. (If one of them is `nil`, this is a slightly different story, but it's not likely we would have gotten here if that were true.))

Here again, an `NSArray` is being assigned to an `NSMutableArray` pointer:

```
NSMutableArray * sortedArray = [newArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
_finalSortedArray=sortedArray;
```

More importantly, as with `CurrentTStamp`, there's no reason for the intermediate `sortedArray` variable. Just assign directly to whatever variable you want to use for the final list. Even more importantly, `_finalSortedArray` *is not mutable* after this. This is a serious problem if it's an ivar, and because the return type of the method says that it's mutable. The caller expects to be able to mutate the returned value, but will get an exception if it tries.

### Miscellaneous:

This requires a bit of caution:

```
int FLEX_START_TIME=[[flex_task objectForKey:@"TASK_START_TIME"] intValue];

if(FLEX_START_TIME==0)
```

If `flex_task`'s value for the given key is somehow `nil`, the return will be a false 0 value. (The value of `objectForKey:` is `nil` if the key doesn't exist, e.g., if you were to mistype it as mentioned above, and `intValue` sent to `nil` produces `0`.)

If this is code that's being run by the general public, get rid of the `NSLog()`s. It is dumping data into the system's log files that doesn't (seem to) have a reason to be there. (If it isn't, strongly consider getting rid of the `NSLog()`s anyways and using breakpoints. You can have Xcode perform an action like `p LOWER_LIMIT_TSTAMP` when it hits, and then continue automatically.)

The long whitespace between sections and repeated "banner" comments are unnecessary and just make the code that much harder to follow.

A few of these things that I've mentioned should generate compiler warnings; you should pay attention to compiler warnings and not consider your code complete until they are addressed. You should also try using the Analyzer tool in Xcode. It will help you spot problems with conditionals and control flow.

---

<sup>*</sup>Really, even if you can, but that's probably a subject for another answer.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the time spent typing all this!

Comment: Glad I could help. Allow me to suggest that you don't mark this as accepted right off the bat: other people might have things to say as well.

Comment: `[_strictTasksArray objectAtIndex:0];` is `_strictTasksArray[0]` ... do you mean `_strictTasksArray.firstObject` which also protects against index out of bounds?

Comment: Absolutely a good option, @nhgrif, although bounds checking is done here before that access.